Why LDP crashes when using w registers but not with x registers
On Aarch64 assembly for Apply M1 I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using LDP with w 32-bit registers. The same problem does not happen when I use x 64-bit registers instead.
Example using x which works fine:
.global _start

_start:
    mov x0, #1 // arg1
    mov x1, #2 // arg2

    stp x0, x1, [sp, #-16]! // push these values to the stack before we branch to another location.

    bl add_nums
    mov x2, x0   // save x0 to w2, so we don't lose once we restore the original x0 from stack

    ldp x0, x1, [sp], #16 // pop off x0, x1 with the values they were before going into add_numbs

    // Exit program
    mov x0, 0       // 0 status code
    mov x16, 1
    svc 0

add_nums:
    // stores the result back to x0, that is why we need to store the original
    // x0 on _start into the stack, so we could restore it later.
    add x0, x0, x1
    ret


The problematic code. It is the same as the previous one, I just updated everything use w instead of x registers, and with that the range modified in the stack point also is half o the size:
_start:
    mov w0, #1 // arg1
    mov w2, #2 // arg2

    stp w0, w2, [sp, #-8]! // push these values to the stack before we branch to another location.

    bl add_nums
    mov w2, w0   // save w0 to w2, so we don't lose once we restore the original w0 from stack

    ldp w0, w2, [sp], #8 // pop off w0, w2 with the values they were before going into add_numbs

    // Exit program
    mov x0, 0       // 0 status code
    mov x16, 1
    svc 0

add_nums:
    // stores the result back to w0, that is why we need to store the original
    // w0 on _start into the stack, so we could restore it later.
    add w0, w0, w2
    ret


The full error is:

thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=259, address=0x16fdfe948)

Apparently A64 should support LDP with w registers https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/l/A64-Data-Transfer-Instructions/LDP--A64-?lang=en.

Does stp w0, w2, [sp, #-16]! work? I suspect the problem is misaligning the stack pointer not the w registers as such.

The stack pointer. must always be a multiple of 16.  It is an error if it isn't.  You must always modify the sp in multiples of 16, even if you're storing smaller objects to it.

Yes, using 16-byte slot with w register works. Thanks you both for clarifying it!

Thanks to Jester and Frank's comments it makes sense now.

For AArch64, sp must be 16-byte aligned whenever it is used to access memory. This is enforced by AArch64 hardware - reference.

It means for AArch64 the stack point must always be multiple of 16-byte even if the data being stored there is smaller than that. Otherwise that kind of error EXC_BAD_ACCESS will occur.
